# Why are log4net threads stuck on a wait?

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net

Last week one of our test servers ran out of disk space on the log drive. After freeing up disk space, I still have several threads with call stacks that seem to be stuck inside of log4net AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend, which is confusing since I'm expecting log4net to be thread safe.

1. Am I reading the stack correct in seeing the threads as being stuck?
2. Is the stack indicating that the thread is stuck at 'lock(this)' or elsewhere? My guess is elsewhere, since I would expect to see something like, Monitor.Enter if it was stuck at lock(this).
3. One of the threads seems to show DoAppend in the middle of rolling over to a new file. Could it be that all of the DoAppend threads are blocked on the creation of this file? However, I would expect these threads to become unblocked after we freed disk space.

**Any help understanding why log4net seems to be stuck across so many threads is appreciated.**

Here is an example call stack showing a thread blocked at a wait inside of DoAppend:

> ntdll.dll!_**NtWaitForMultipleObjects**@20()  + 0x15 bytes
>       ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0x15 bytes
>       KERNELBASE.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()  + 0x36 bytes 
>       kernel32.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation@20()  + 0x8e bytes 
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.**AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend**(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0x3e bytes 
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa0 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa9 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x4a bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x5e bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Core.LogImpl.Info(object message) + 0x27 bytes

Here is the source from log4net AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend

```
public void DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) 
{
    // This lock is absolutely critical for correct formatting
    // of the message in a multi-threaded environment.  Without
    // this, the message may be broken up into elements from
    // multiple thread contexts (like get the wrong thread ID).

    lock(this)
    {
        if (m_closed)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Error("Attempted to append to closed appender named ["+m_name+"].");
            return;
        }

        // prevent re-entry
        if (m_recursiveGuard)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            m_recursiveGuard = true;

            if (FilterEvent(loggingEvent) && PreAppendCheck())
            {
                this.Append(loggingEvent);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Error("Failed in DoAppend", ex);
        }
#if !MONO && !NET_2_0
        // on .NET 2.0 (and higher) and Mono (all profiles), 
        // exceptions that do not derive from System.Exception will be
        // wrapped in a RuntimeWrappedException by the runtime, and as
        // such will be catched by the catch clause above
        catch
        {
            // Catch handler for non System.Exception types
            ErrorHandler.Error("Failed in DoAppend (unknown exception)");
        }
#endif
        finally
        {
            m_recursiveGuard = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my log4net settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="g:\logfiles\mySerivceName\" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="'myServiceName.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'-00.log'"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level [%3thread] [%-50.50stacktrace] %message %newline"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
        <to value="alerts@myCompanyName.com" />
        <from value="servicename@localnetwork" />
        <subject value="${COMPUTERNAME} - Error Generated" />
        <smtpHost value="mySmtpServerIpAddress" />
        <bufferSize value="2" />
        <lossy value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level [%3thread] [%-50.50stacktrace] %message %newline" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="ERROR" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**The DoAppend stack that is rolling over to a new file**

> ```
> mscorlib.dll!System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(char value) Line 953 + 0xb bytes
>   mscorlib.dll!System.IO.PathHelper.Append(char value) Line 139 + 0x18 bytes
>   mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(string path, bool fullCheck, int maxPathLength, bool expandShortPaths) Line 620
>   mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(string path) Line 170 + 0x24 bytes
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.LockingModelBase.CreateStream(string filename, bool append, System.IO.FileShare fileShare) + 0x35 bytes     
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.ExclusiveLock.OpenFile(string filename, bool append, System.Text.Encoding encoding) + 0x2d bytes      
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.OpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x1ac bytes  
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.OpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x189 bytes 
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.SafeOpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x2d bytes     
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.PrepareWriter() + 0x13 bytes  
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.PreAppendCheck() + 0x32 bytes 
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xe0 bytes 
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa0 bytes      
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa9 bytes      
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x4a bytes      
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x5e bytes      
>   log4net.dll!log4net.Core.LogImpl.Info(object message) + 0x27 bytes
> ```

Here is another call stack on the same machine, different process, also hung:

> clr.dll!AwareLock::Contention()  + 0x10d bytes
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0x3e bytes 
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa0 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa9 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x4a bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x5e bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Core.LogImpl.Info(object message) + 0x27 bytes

And in this second process on the same machine, there is also a thread that seems to be blocked trying to rollover.

> MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll!_memcpy()  + 0x21e bytes
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Buffer._Memcpy(byte* dest, byte* src, int len) Line 484 + 0x20 bytes    C#
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Buffer.Memcpy(byte* dest, byte* src, int len) Line 401  C#
>       mscorlib.dll!string.FillStringChecked(string dest, int destPos, string src) Line 1523 + 0xf bytes   C#
>       mscorlib.dll!string.ConcatArray(string[] values, int totalLength) Line 3340 C#
>       mscorlib.dll!string.Concat(object[] args) Line 3180 + 0xa bytes C#
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.OpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x162 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.OpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x189 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.SafeOpenFile(string fileName, bool append) + 0x2d bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.FileAppender.PrepareWriter() + 0x13 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.PreAppendCheck() + 0x32 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xe0 bytes 
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa0 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent) + 0xa9 bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x4a bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(System.Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, log4net.Core.Level level, object message, System.Exception exception) + 0x5e bytes
>       log4net.dll!log4net.Core.LogImpl.Info(object message) + 0x27 bytes

Comment: So you're saying these errors are coming from within the CLR and Kernel? If that's true, I agree with you. But what part of the call stack drew you to that conclusion?

Comment: Well, callstack rather shows us that we have a deadlock here. Did the application crash or it's still working? `lock` won't timeout by itself, so it's stuck somewhere attempting to write to file where it failed on lack of disk space.

Comment: Certain threads froze. Aspects of the app remained responsive. But pieces relying on the blocked threads never recovered. Ultimately had to restart the server. I too believe the deadlock occurred in log4net. Just didn't think that was possible/likely.

Comment: I too have run into deadlocks in DoAppend. Mine were due to me intercepting trace messages, but I still don't fully understand why. What does your code look like?

Comment: Any update on this, guys?

Comment: I also see this behaviour here an then appearing... :-(. For a project beeing debuged in ISSExpress I can very rarely reproduce it. After server seems not repsonding I  break in VS and see thread beeing stuck in ...ApenderSkeleton.DoAppend. In my current debug session one thread stuck at RollingFileAppender.AdjustFileBeforeAppend

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behavior of log4net multiple times here on stack overflow. When you run out of diskspace the fileappender seems to start blocking. I guess this is a bug in the appender, so logging this as bug seems right for this case.